# Android - Stuck on create new application screen

Tags: android, eclipse

I cant go beyond the create new project screen, showing message of choose theme even when all possible theme options are selected. How to get along it and continue?

[image]

Comment: ... what is the question, really?

Comment: Need to choose compile with. Set it to the latest SDK.

Comment: also install the relevant SDK